# Help choosing a servo motor

Tags: servo

I am struggling to choose servo motor for my project. There are two servos on ebay. Th First one is named Only "Towerpro micro 9g servo" and the second one that is cheaper is named as a "Towerpro 9g Digital servo".
The Links are:

Servo1: http://www.ebay.in/itm/TowerPro-SG90-9g-Mini-Servo-9-gram-Servo-RC-Robotics-/201386256243?hash=item2ee38e6773

Servo2: http://www.ebay.in/itm/251928442829?aff_source=Sok-Goog

My Problem is that **I am confused with the name "Digital Servo"**. Its cheaper but I a afraid that will it work as normal.
Please help me.

Are both the **same** product, but with a different name?

Answer (score 1):

Servos are digital by definition.  All you have there is two sellers that are selling the same product, but they are describing them slightly differently.  They are both SG90 servos. They are both digital (they require a digital PWM signal to control them, hence they are digital).

However, here's a little hint: Add the postage costs on to the cost of the servo - you'll see there's not that much difference in price - only 3 rupees between them.  That's about ¢5 or 3p.

Comment: On ebay I've seen stepper motors erroneously labelled as servos and real servos labelled as digital servos, to differentiate from the misnamed stepper ones. Usually the price is a good indicator of which is which, but comparing with similar products is the safest bet.